# Generalized minimal residuals: eigenvalues and sets of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Can someone help me on this exercise (2 parts)? Thanks!

> Suppose that $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a set whose convex hull
>   contains $0$ in it's interior (so $S$ is contained in no half-plane
>   disjoint from the origin). How can you show that there is no $p$
>   $\in P_1$ (where $P_1$ is the set of polynomials of degree $1$ with
>   $p(0)=1$) such that $||p||_S<1$?

My idea would be to start from the opposition and to search for a contradiction. Suppose there is a $p \in P_1$ for which $||p||_S < 1$ ($p(0)=1$) and thus $||p||_S = \sup_{z \in S}|p(z)| < 1$. But because of the setting ($p(0)=1$), the supremum should be at least $1$. Contradiction.

> Now, let $A$ be a matrix whose spetrum $\Lambda(A)$ (which is the
>   multiset of its eigenvalues) has the above properties. Show that there
>   is no $p \in P_1$ such that $||p(A)||<1$.

I really have no idea on how to solve this part... Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Just for clarification, does "$\Lambda(A)$ has the above properties" mean that the convex hull of the spectrum contains $0$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in the first part. Compactness of $S$, continuity of $p$, and $p(0)=1$ imply that the $\sup$ of $p$ over $S$ cannot be smaller than $1$.

For the second question, consider using the *field of values*, which is the set
$$
F(A) = \{x^*Ax: x\in\mathbb{C}^n, x^*x=1\}
$$
and the *numerical radius*
$$
\nu(A)=\max_{z\in F(A)}|z|=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}|x^*Ax|.
$$
You can write $\max$ here because $F$ is compact (and $|\cdot|$ is continuous). It is also convex. Moreover, it is true that the convex hull of $\Lambda(A)$ is contained in $F(A)$. Note that $\nu(A)$ is a lower bound of $\|A\|_2$ ($\nu(A)\leq\|A\|_2$).

Let $p\in P_1$, that is, $p(z)=1+\alpha z$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. Since $0\in\mathrm{conv}(\Lambda(A))$ and $\mathrm{conv}(\Lambda(A))\subset F(A)$, there is a $y\in\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $y^*y=1$ and $y^*Ay=0$. Since $\|p(A)\|_2\geq\nu(p(A))$, we have
$$
\|p(A)\|_2\geq\nu(I+\alpha A) = \max_{\|x\|_2=1}|x^*(I+\alpha A)x|
\geq|y^*(I+\alpha A)y|=y^*y=1.
$$